# When using mylatexformat background image is not shown

Tags: format-files

In order to optimize the generation of thousands of PDF documents, I'm struggling with mylatexformat that will include the main packages.

To structure our work, I've put all the common packages in a file that should be precompiled, and all our client related definitions in another file (in a second step I will also try to precompile some packages and definitions for each client).

But the generated PDF output doesn't include the letterhead background. The PDF also shows a page number whereas I've defined that no page number should be visible. When I'm not working with mylatexformat, this Hello World ! example is working correctly.

**penarch-common-precompiled.tex**

```
\def\encodingdefault{OT1}\normalfont
\everyjob\expandafter{\the\everyjob\def\encodingdefault{TU}\normalfont}


\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{parskip}            % vertical space between paragraphs
\usepackage{xcolor}             % foreground (text, rules, etc.) and background colour management
\usepackage{soul}               % hyphenatable letterspacing, underlining, overstriking, highlighting
\usepackage{geometry}           % customize page layout
\usepackage{enumitem}           % enumerate, itemize and description lists
\usepackage{hyperref}           % hypertext links
\usepackage{qrcode}             % generate QR codes
\usepackage{fancyhdr}           % headers and footers
\usepackage{graphicx}           % support for graphics
\usepackage{tabularx}           % tables with adjustable width columns
\usepackage{scalerel}           % vertically scaling and stretching objects
\usepackage{amssymb}            % symbols found in the AMS symbol font msam and msbm
\usepackage{multicol}           % define a multicols environment which typesets text in multiple columns
\usepackage{pst-barcode}        % printing of barcodes, including qr codes
\usepackage{scrextend}          % required to left indent address block
\usepackage{marvosym}           % includes euro symbol
\usepackage{colortbl}           % background color for row, columns or individual cells in a table
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}  % absolute positioning of text on the page
\usepackage{tikz}               % package for creating graphics
\usepackage{setspace}           % set spacing between lines
\usepackage{wallpaper}          % use pdf as background image (letterhead)

\title{Sections and Chapters}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue}     % define the layout of hyperlinks
\newcommand{\hlc}[2][yellow]{
    {\sethlcolor{#1} \hl{#2}}
}                                               % define a new command to highlight in another color
\newcommand{\dole}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node[anchor=east,xshift=0mm,yshift=-1.2mm]{#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}                                               % make a font to is aligned 1.2mm beneath the normal line

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}     % define a new column type for a fixed-width centered-aligned column - middle vertical alignment
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{#1}}    % define a new column type for a fixed-width right-aligned column - middle vertical alignment
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}   % define a new column type for a fixed-width left-aligned column - middle vertical alignment
\newcolumntype{F}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}   % define a new column type for a fixed-width left-aligned column - top vertical alignment

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{10mm}                % 1 generic horizontal unit is equivalent to 10mm for a textblock
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{10mm}                 % 1 generic vertical unit is equivalent to 10mm for a textblock
\textblockorigin{0mm}{0mm}                      % top left corner set as origin for a textblock

\endofdump
```

**penarch-client.tex**

```
\usepackage{fontspec}                       % support for OpenType fonts

\geometry{
    a4paper,
    left=30mm,
    right=25mm,
    headheight=115pt,
    top=4.5cm,
    headsep=0cm,
    bottom=3.5cm,
    footskip=95pt
}

\pagenumbering{gobble}                          % sets page numbering off

\linespread{0.8}                                % change the line spacing for entire document
\setmainfont[Path=./fonts/,
    BoldItalicFont=CALIBRIZ.TTF,
    BoldFont      =CALIBRIB.TTF,
    ItalicFont    =CALIBRII.TTF]{CALIBRI.TTF}   % set main font to Calibri

\ULCornerWallPaper{1}{letterhead.pdf}
```

**hello-world.tex**

```
%&penarch-common-precompiled
\input{penarch-client}
\input{penarch-hyphenation-dutch}

\begin{document}


Hello World !


\end{document}
```

**My shell script**

```
xelatex -ini -jobname="penarch-common-precompiled" "&xelatex" mylatexformat.ltx penarch-common-precompiled.tex
xelatex hello-world.tex
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must add `\endofdump`. Without it mylatexformat will ignore everything in the preamble until \begin{document}:

```
\endofdump
\input{penarch-client}
\input{penarch-hyphenation-dutch}

\begin{document}


Hello World !


\end{document}
```